# Does namespace or folder structure affect the performance of an assembly?

Tags: c#

I can't help but wonder if namespaces or project folder structure effect the performance of the assembly. My gut says *"no, but it may possibly effect compile time"*.

Thinking about performance always get's in the way, especially if you're a novice. I can't help it! So, I thought I'd ask my fellow game developers who I respect and admire.

Comment: I don't want to compete with @PlayDeezGames answer: it really won't. In dynamic languages it may. In SQL Server it can hit you for up to 30% cost. Never in C#.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Everyone has explained how premature optimization is a bad idea (which it is): however I will explain why it actually makes no difference whatsoever (except for cases where you use reflection - more on that later).

## Static Reference In Code

The CLR (and therefore MSIL - which is what C# compiles to) actually has no notion or concept of namespaces. A type (class, enum, etc.) is referred to by its full name (e.g. `System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable`) and 'full stops' are just as opaque (meaningful) as any other character in the name. The whole concept of namespaces is something that C# (or whichever language you are using) provides for you. However, in terms of raw MSIL the type name doesn't actually matter either.

In MSIL you never refer to something by its name. Everything in an assembly (dll or exe) has a certain type of handle. For example a type has a `TypeHandle` and anything contained by a type has a `MemberHandle`: both are a 32bit integer. So when you call a method you don't write `call <MethodName> on <TypeName> in <Assembly>` in MSIL - instead you write `call <MethodHandle> on <TypeHandle> in <Assembly>`. Therefore getting a type that has 5000 characters in its name takes the same amount of time that one with 5 would. The actual names are stored in a separate place in the assembly: only so that you can use reflection to get them, or for compilers (in other words the names are only stored "for your information") - this is called the metadata.

I think there is a way to get ILDASM to give you the raw MSIL - but I am not sure.

## Accessed Using Reflection

Because you are doing a string comparison between the type name you want and the names available in the assembly it makes a difference: string comparisons are a O(n) operation. However, this time is ***miniscule*** compared to the total cost of reflection and is **completely negligible** (it will make nanoseconds of a difference) - don't even worry about it.

## Summary

This is why premature optimization is really bad - you assumed this was a bottleneck where in reality there is no faster or slower way to do it.

Comment: Passing `/bytes` to `ildasm` prints a lot of hex codes for things, including IL opcodes and (if applicable) tokens and handles. You can also have it dump metadata tables in raw form.

Comment: @JoshPetrie indeed. I going more for an option "IL instructions but don't lookup names please" - which I **think** it had: unless I mixing up Cecil and ildasm. *Edit:* Oh right, that was probably it.

Answer (score 19):

Answer: No, your project folder structure and namespaces will not have an appreciable effect on performance.

A word about performance.

It is written:

Premature Optimization is the Root of All Evil.

I recall being a novice.

I wanted to have the best code ever.

I see you want the same thing.

However, worrying about things like this will not help you.

Just go write some games and gain some experience.

Worry about performance later.

Comment: This is good advice, but unfortunately I don't think it actually answers the question.

Answer (score 3):

The organization of your source files on disk will not affect the performance of the compiled assembly. Nor will the depth or breadth of your namespaces use within the source code.

When you look at the ECMA standard for the CLI (#335), specifically Partition II chapter 22 thereof, you can find the metadata format used to describe types in an assembly (the `TypeDef` logical table). You can see there that the type name and type namespace are both indices into the string heap -- indices in CLI metadata are pseudo-dynamic, in that they are designed to always be a minimal size necessary to index all the available items, so the size of the string heap index in actual bytes may vary but it will be the same for all types.

Any access to the namespace or name through the metadata will thus be constant time within the scope of that assembly. Access to data surrounding the namespace index will similarly be constant-time (there won't need to be any linear-time string length computations to "skip past" the namespace string in the type metadata, since the actual string is in the heap).

So it doesn't really(*) matter how many or how deeply nested your namespaces are -- until you access them in code via reflection and start doing linear-time string operations on them. But at that point that's true of any string operation you perform.

(*) the *number* of unique namespaces and names and other strings will obviously increase the size of the string heap, but any impact this has on performance is extremely low-level and isn't always necessarily negative.